# Iterative 'using stack' vs Recursive implementaion of quick sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, quicksort

I found [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-quick-sort/) article on iterative Quick Sort.
If we implement the iterative solution of a recursive algorithm using stack, will it be faster? If yes, how is it different from the recursive stack?

Comment: While the linked thread is dealing with Java, the same principles apply to all imperative languages as well, including C++.

Comment: It's telling that the article you linked doesn't provide any measurements of the actual performance of any of the code.

Comment: Thanks @amit for the quick response. But my question is a bit different i guess, correct me if i am wrong. In the given iterative implementation it is done using custom stack. How it is different from the recursive stack? Is custom stack implementation is better than the recursive one?

Comment: @KrishnaAnaril No, and it is stated there (I think in comments to accepted answer) - the custom stack is less optimized than the built in one (unless you are going to spend tons of time on optimizing it) - and thus the recursive is more likely to be better. The related article benchmark the two approaches with a given stack implementation and giving the tools to benchmark any stack implementation simply.

Comment: when you use a custom stack to implement this algorithm you are implementing the iterative version; the other, obvious difference is what get's saved on the stack: for the recursive version the whole context is saved (e.g. registers, sp, etc..) while with a custom stack it's just the values that need sorting.